# Definition of $[G:C_G(x)]$

Tags: group-theory, notation

What is the meaning of $[G:C_G(x)]$ in group theory? Is this equivalent to $\frac{|G|}{|Z_G(x)|}$, or to $|Z_G(x)|$?

Comment: Do you mean the index of the centralizer of $x$?

Comment: Maybe, i don't know definition of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C_G(x)$ is the *centralizer* of $x$ in $G$. That is, $\{ g \in G \mid gxg^{-1} = x \}$ or equivalently, $\{ g \in G \mid gx = xg \}$.

The $[G : H]$ notation means the *index* of $H$ in $G$, and it is defined as the number of cosets of $H$ in $G$. Lagrange's theorem says that this is equal to $\frac{G}{H}$.

By the way, for this particular $H = C_G(x)$, this has a very useful value. It is the size of the conjugacy class of $x$, i.e., $\{ gxg^{-1} \mid g \in G \}$. Are you by chance studying the class equation?

EDIT: $C_G(x)$ is in fact a subgroup. Obviously $e \in C_G(x)$. Now, we show that if $a, b \in C_G(x)$, then $ab^{-1} \in C_G(x)$.
$$(ab^{-1}) x = ab^{-1}x(bb^{-1}) = ab^{-1}(xb)b^{-1} = ab^{-1}(bx) b^{-1} = axb^{-1} = x(ab^{-1})$$

Comment: But $C_G$ isn't a subgroup.

Comment: So what is $[(Z_5:C_{Z_5}(1))]$?

Comment: First, what is the centralizer of $1$. (Hint, which elements commute with $1$?)

Comment: Answer $1$ is correct?

Comment: When does $1 + a = a + 1$?

Comment: $Z_G(x)=C_G(x)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $Z_G(x)$ (is it just another notation for centralizer?)

Comment: $C_{Z_5}(1)=Z_5$, $\frac{|Z_5|}{|C_{Z_5}(1)|}=1$, so answer 1.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. (In general, the center is a subset of a centralizer. And in an abelian group, everything commutes, so centralizers are just the whole thing)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to know that $Z(G) \subseteq C_G(x)$ for all $x \in G$. In fact $Z(G) = \bigcap_{x \in G} C_G(x)$.